# Does IBM have a publicly available tutorial on applied quantum computing and how does one use it? Any Reviews of the Tutorial?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, resource-request

I found this link and I am wondering if anyone has used it to learn or develop applications?  I would like to know if people find it worth the time.    I am reading the material by the way.

https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/developers/

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to post the "link" that you mentioned.

To answer your question, yes IBM offers some very educational tutorials through their textbook [found here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/introduction.html). I am new to quantum computing myself, but I have found these tutorials were sufficient to get my feet up off the ground and start doing some projects on their machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://qiskit.org/documentation/. Scroll down to the tutorial part. I guess this is what you are looking for.